# What setting change would cause my Libre Office document to decrease the usable size of the page?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, headers, margins, footers

I must have accidentally hit some key combination that caused the settings for my document to change, because all of a sudden I went from around page 420 to page 450, and the text no longer fit on the page as previously.

I'm copying pages over from two other documents to this third document. I have them all set up with the same margins and page width, height, and orientation.

All of a sudden, though (whatever change it was, I wish it would confirm that I really wanted ot make it, because I didn't) copying one page fills one page plus a couple of lines - this has thrown my whole document out of whack!

The margins are the same, and the page size is the same, so what is it?

It looks to me like it could be that the header and/or footer have increased in height. How could that happen? How can I change it back to what it was before?

### UPDATE

When I was trying to see on one of my "good" documents what the header properties are, it had a + sign to click; I did that, and it increased the header height! THEN it showd a down-arrow to click for properties, but it's too late for that now - I wanted to see what the correct values should be, but now they've changed. I must have accidentally clicked that danged + sign on the other document by accident. Arggghhhh!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've accidentally added a header (apparently that's what I had inadvertently done), you can 86 it by selecting Insert > Header and clearing the "Default" check box. Not very intuitive, but...oh, well, it works now.